# Interactive Brokers TWS API Error: Cash Quantity cannot be used for this order

Tags: java, interactive-brokers, ib-api

I'm trying to place an order using TWS Java API. I want to set a cash quantity instead of the quantity of shares. Below is my code:

```
...
Contract contract = new Contract();
contract.symbol("IBM");
contract.secType("STK");
contract.exchange("SMART");
contract.currency("USD");

Order order = new Order();
order.action("BUY");
order.orderType("MKT");
order.cashQty("500");
m_socket.placeOrder(NextOrderId, contract, order);
```

When I run this code, I get an error:

> Cash Quantity cannot be used for this order

If I use the quantity of shares using `order.totalQuantity()`, the order is placed successfully.
How can I set a cash quantity instead of a share quantity?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you found any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Cash Quantity orders can only be made on Forex trades through the api. Here is a link to their [docs](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/basic_orders.html#:%7E:text=Cash%20Quantity%20Orders-,Order%20order%20%3D%20new%20Order()%3B,order.cashQty(cashQty)%3B,-Limit%20if%20Touched). As you can see, cashQty only shows under a forex trade.  I ran into this issue as well and now use this basic calculation for figuring out how many shares I can buy based on the amount I want to invest.

(amount you want to spend) / (price of stock) = # of shares you can buy